# Rendering code works on desktop but not on android

Tags: android, libgdx, render

```
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam1.combined);
    sb.begin();
    if (i < cash) {
        MyGame.font90.draw(sb, "i: " + Math.round(i), 300, 600);
        i += cash / 75;
    } else {
        MyGame.font90.draw(sb, "Cash: " + cash, 300, 600);
    }
    sb.end();
```

So I am rendering this string+integer code inside the render method in libgdx to show how much money one has made. It is meant to render up until the actual money you have made starting from 0. I declared i=0 inside the constructor of the class and this entire code works fine on desktop but when I try it on android it just says "Cash: 0".

Comment: Is i actually 0? What happens on the desktop?

Comment: Is `MyGame` an external library?

Comment: type of the __cash__ and __i__ is? And you can post whole method here, it would be usefull for those, who are answering

Comment: It seems that i is not increasing after each step. MyGame is an internal class of the game wich has public variables such as the cash to make it easier to transfer the values from screen to screen. cash and i are both float

Comment: put some logs/breakpoints inside your render method and see what values your variables have